# Oracle. Pass result to custom function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a custom function which is supposed to calculate upper and lower quartiles. I want to compute it in a following way:

```
SELECT QUARTILE_UTILS.GET_QUARTILE(0.25, YEAR_1_FTE),  
       QUARTILE_UTILS.GET_QUARTILE(0.75, YEAR_1_FTE)
FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE FIRM_ID=999;
```

So it looks like an aggregate function. It receives a number to calculate a quartule(.25 or .75) and a collection of numbers. So here is the function body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY QUARTILE_UTILS AS
  FUNCTION GET_QUARTILE(PERCENTILE NUMBER, DATASET NUMBERS_ARRAY) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    REMINDER NUMBER := 0;
    I SIMPLE_INTEGER := 0;
    RESULT NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
    ....
    RETURN RESULT;
  END;
END QUARTILE_UTILS;
```

And as you can see, I defined a custom data type. Here it is:

```
create or replace TYPE NUMBERS_ARRAY AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

However, it still doens't work. When I try to execute I receive such error:

```
PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_QUARTILE'
```

As far, as I understand my definition of collection of number is incorrect. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What data type is YEAR_1_FTE? Presumably not a nested table type. You want to aggregate over all the values from the table - I think - so are you trying to write [a user-defined aggregate function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm)? Or do you want to turn the values from the table into a collection and pass that to your current function?

Comment: @AlexPoole YEAR_1_FTE is just a number. So yes, I just need to pass a collection of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is expecting a collection, not a simple number; so you can use [the `COLLECT()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions031.htm) and cast what that produces to the expected table type:

```
SELECT QUARTILE_UTILS.GET_QUARTILE(0.25, CAST(COLLECT(YEAR_1_FTE) AS NUMBERS_ARRAY)),
       QUARTILE_UTILS.GET_QUARTILE(0.75, CAST(COLLECT(YEAR_1_FTE) AS NUMBERS_ARRAY))
FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE FIRM_ID=999;
```

You might want to investigate [user-defined aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm) as an alternative though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw this article about user-defined aggregate functions. I saw, that I should develop custom data type. For me it's just looks wierd that I should perform all these steps just to pass an array of integers.

Comment: You have to create an array of integers from the individual numbers in each row. That doesn't seem unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is offtopic . But maybe it helps you.

```
with abc as (select 1 lp from dual
                union all
                select 2 from dual
                union all
                select 4 from dual
                union all
                select 5 from dual
                union all
                select 8 from dual
                union all
                select 9 from dual
                union all
                select 10 from dual
                union all
             select 12 from dual)
select median(case when quartiles =1 then lp else null end), /* .25 */
       median(case when quartiles =3 then lp else null end) /* .75 */
from
( 
select 
       lp, ntile(4) over(order by lp) quartiles
from abc
)
```

Oracle also has `PERCENTILE_DISC,PERCENTILE_CONT` analytic/aggregation function.